# Why items in Android menu gets add after each swipe?

Tags: android, android-fragments, menu, menuitem

I wanted to move some of my items in toolbar from right to left, for this I have used `android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView`, but I have ran into trouble.

My activity contains three fragments. Now for example if I open menu from toolbar at app startup, all is fine. But if I swipe to B from A, items in the menu gets double. On startup menu contains two items, but after swipe to another fragment, items get double(it becomes four and so on).

I have tried searching internet, but this type of question is not posted anywhere.

My layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        >

   <cn.nekocode.toolbarindicator.ToolbarIndicator
    android:id="@+id/indicator"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />
<android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView
    android:id="@+id/amvMenu"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"/>
 </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

   </LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

ViewPager viewPager;
TabsPagerAdapter adapter;
Toolbar toolbar;
private SharedPreferences savedPreferences;
ToolbarIndicator toolbarIndicator;
ActionMenuView amvMenu;

CharSequence Titles[] = {"one", "two", "three"};
int Numboftabs = 3;

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    savedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
//here is the problem
 toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
    if (toolbar != null) {
        toolbar.setTitle("");
        toolbar.setSubtitle("");
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    }
 adapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), Titles, Numboftabs);
    // Assigning ViewPager View and setting the adapter
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
    // Assiging the fadingIndicator View
     toolbarIndicator = (ToolbarIndicator) this.findViewById(R.id.indicator);
    amvMenu = (ActionMenuView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.amvMenu);
    amvMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new ActionMenuView.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
            return onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem);
        }
    });
toolbarIndicator.setViewPager(viewPager);
}


 @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, amvMenu.getMenu());
    return true;
}

//handling the tap on the menu's items
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    switch (id) {
        case R.id.action_settings: {//open settings
            startActivity(new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class));
            return true;
        }
        case R.id.exit:{
            android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
            System.exit(1);
        }
        default:
            break;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


}
```

If I edit this line `getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, amvMenu.getMenu());` to `getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);`
 all gets fine but item appears on right again.

Comment: Try to clear the menu in `onCreateOptionsMenu()` before the inflate like this `amvMenu.getMenu().clear();` Does this help?

Comment: Thanks! it worked. You can post your solution as answer so that i can accept it.

Comment: Did it. Glad I could help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the comment section: Clear the menu in `onCreateOptionsMenu()` before the inflate.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    amvMenu.getMenu().clear(); // add this line
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, amvMenu.getMenu());
    return true;
}
```